# Order records by mapping collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 collections as follows

**Author**:

```
   {id:'1',name:'JK', bookCount:3}
   {id:'2',name:'SS', bookCount:2}
   {id:'3',name:'CC', bookCount:4}
```

**Book**: ( authorId : foreign key to Author collections)

```
   {name:'Book 1',authorId:1}
   {name:'Book 2',authorId:1}
   {name:'Book 3',authorId:1}
   {name:'Book 4',authorId:2}
   {name:'Book 5',authorId:2}
   {name:'Book 6',authorId:3}
   {name:'Book 7',authorId:3}
   {name:'Book 8',authorId:3}
   {name:'Book 9',authorId:3}
```

I want to write a mongo query, which gives books,ordered by -> number of books written by corresponding author in ascending order, i.e

```
   {name:'Book 4',authorId:2}
   {name:'Book 5',authorId:2}
   {name:'Book 1',authorId:1}
   {name:'Book 2',authorId:1}  
   {name:'Book 3',authorId:1}
   {name:'Book 6',authorId:3}
    .......
```

How should I go about it. Thanx in advance! :)

Comment: you can't join multiple collections in MongoDB directly in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your output you should required only aggregation on **Book** collection and the aggregation query as below :

```
db.book.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$authorId",
    "names": {
      "$push": "$name"
    },
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$names"
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "count": 1
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "name": "$names",
    "authorId": "$_id",
    "_id": 0
  }
})
```

Comment: The OP is trying to order "books" by the alphabetical name of the author from the "author" collection.

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

1) group your data based on authorId and take the count and 
        also make an array containing all the books in that group

2)  unwind the book array

3) sort based on the count field which you have created during grouping

4) finally project in the format you require.

```
db.book.aggregate([
{"$group": { "_id" : "$authorId", "count": {"$sum" : 1}, 
  "arr" :   {"$push" : "$name" }}
},
{"$unwind" :"$arr"},
{"$sort":{"$count": 1 }},
{"$project": {"name" : "$arr", "authorId" : "$_id"}
}
 ]);
```

Comment: You are not reading the question. The OP want their "books" collection ordered by the name of the author from the "author" collection. Hence a "join"